# Encoded URL in Azure Template

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create an ARM template and I'm running into an issue when trying to provide a templateLink in my parent template.

In the parent template, I am trying to reference a list of other template files that will be used.  I'm doing this by adding the following JSON object

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "name": "linkedTemplate",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "[concat(variables('baseURL'), 'settings%2Ejson/raw', variables('queryString'))]",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And I have baseURL is the path to a gitlab installation defined as

```
    "baseURL": "https://<URL>/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/shared_services%2F",
```

For the GitLab API to work, it needs the portion of the URL after files to be an encoded URL referencing the path to the file inside the git repository.  So instead of having / and . in the URL it needs %2E and %2F for that section.  So in my case, I'm trying to access the following URL

https://whatever.com/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/shared_services%2Fsettings%2Ejson/raw

However, when I run the template using the azure CLI tool with the following command,

```
az group deployment validate --debug -g example --template-file parent.json --parameters "@./parameters.json"
```

I get the following error

Unable to download deployment content from 'https://whatever.com/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/shared_services%2Fsettings.json/raw

It seems like no matter what I try, settings%2Ejson keeps turning into settings.json.  However, the %2F encoded character made it through ok.  So I wasn't sure if there was anything that I could do, to maintain the %2E without the azure CLI tool converting it to a .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, Azure template does not support encore URI in template.

According to your scenario, you could choose the following way.

1.Save your link template as a public URL, you could save it on GitHub or a public Azure Storage account.

2.Although the linked template must be externally available, it does not need to be generally available to the public. You can add your template to a private storage account that is accessible to only the storage account owner. Then, you create a shared access signature (SAS) token to enable access during deployment. You add that SAS token to the URI for the linked template.

The following example shows a parent template that links to another template. The linked template is accessed with a SAS token that is passed in as a parameter.

```
"parameters": {
    "sasToken": { "type": "securestring" }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "name": "linkedTemplate",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "templateLink": {
            "uri": "[concat('https://storagecontosotemplates.blob.core.windows.net/templates/helloworld.json', parameters('sasToken'))]",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
          }
        }
    }
],
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at this solution first.  But ideally we wanted to keep our templates in a git repository so all of the changes were version controlled and we didn't need to push it out somewhere else for the deployment.  And just to make things more difficult, we cannot keep the files in a public repository, which would have solved the issue of trying to access the files.  But if it isn't possible to get an encoded URL into the template, I'll have to look at the storage account suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: You could write a script to upload you template to storage account. Then you could use azure cli to generate SAS token.

Answer (score 0):

ARM templates do have an encode URI function, it has the not so helpful name of [uriComponent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#uricomponent).

Based on your example you could use it like this:

```
"variables": {
    "baseURL": "https://<URL>/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/shared_services",
    "rawPath": "/settings.json/raw",
    "querystring": "?foo=bar"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
        "name": "linkedTemplate",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[concat(variables('baseURL'), uriComponent(variables('rawPath')), variables('queryString'))]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
],
```

The result is:

```
https://<URL>/api/v4/projects/2/repository/files/shared_services%2Fsettings.json%2Fraw?foo=bar
```